# Foreign Character Sets

Tags: php

I have a php script that prompts the user to download a file:

```
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename");
```

Works fine, except with foreign/chinese/arabic char sets; all I get is a load of letters/numbers.

`طرائف الأطفال.txt` becomes `7TcATQCIIZM.txt`.

I need it to retain the original char set filename. Any ideas?

Comment: Upvoted for unexplained downvote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
mysql_query('SET NAMES utf8');
mysql_query('SET CHARACTER SET utf8');
```

Before your PHP query that fetches the filename.

Answer (score 1):

I've found that I can use `mysql_set_charset('utf8');`

I put this just after the connect statement, and now it appears correctly in the download.

Comment: Yep, this is the same as the second line in my answer.  The first line is important if the client ever pushes utf8 content to the database -- see [this link](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?103,46870,47245#msg-47245) for more info.